# how to declare local variable in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database

```
declare my_variable varchar(250)
 set    my_variable= SELECT  Quote( lower(substring_index (doctype, ' ', 1))) from dms_report  LIMIT 1 ;
select my_variable;
```

I am trying run this Query but I am getting an Error on declare and when execute the query I am not getting the results while  SELECT  Quote( lower(substring_index (doctype, ' ', 1))) from   this Query returning some value but I am unable to store it in my_variable please help me where am doing wrong how to declare variable

please suggest me

Comment: Is the code inside a programming block?  That is where `declare` is allowed.

Comment: i havew rite code on sql Qurie  editor in  mysql workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parentheses around the subquery:

```
declare my_variable varchar(250);
set my_variable = (SELECT Quote(lower(substring_index(doctype, ' ',  1)))
                   from dms_report
                   LIMIT 1);
select my_variable;
```

The `declare` itself looks okay, assuming this code is inside a programming block.

EDIT:

If the code is not inside a programming block (such as a stored procedure), then I would just do:

```
 SELECT @var := Quote(lower(substring_index(doctype, ' ',  1)))
 FROM dms_report
 LIMIT 1;

SELECT @var;
```

Comment: still Error coming 1064 and unable to get data

Comment: code block u mean to say that we have write code inside JAVA code?

Comment: u there i have one more query